# Can you insert an image into a grid or detail view, and make it hyperlink to a url determined elsewhere in the grid

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I have a grid view that has a hyperlink field taking info from another field in the row.   This works OK, but rather than just having a text hyperlink, I want to show an image that when clicked on will take the user to the hyperlink.

I know how to include a hyperlink field, and I know how to include an image field, but can you link the two together somehow so that the image picks up the hyperlink created in the grid ~ ie .."~/Members/Create_Vacancy.aspx?Shop_ID={0}"

My current code is ...

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    CssClass="VacancyLink" DataKeyNames="Shop_ID" DataSourceID="LinkSource" 
    GridLines="None" Height="50px" 
    style="width: 74px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: small; font-weight: 700;">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Shop_ID" HeaderText="Shop_ID" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Shop_ID" Visible="False" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Shop_ID" 
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Members/Create_Vacancy.aspx?Shop_ID={0}" 
            ShowHeader="False" Text="Publish New Vacancy" />          
     </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="LinkSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:locumdatabase1ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Shop_ID] FROM [Shop_Detail] WHERE ([Shop_ID] = @Shop_ID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Shop_ID" QueryStringField="Shop_ID" 
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource> &nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text property like this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Shop_ID" 
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Members/Create_Vacancy.aspx?Shop_ID={0}" 
        ShowHeader="False" Text="&lt;img src='Images/img.png' alt='alternate text' border='0'/&gt;" />
```

As shown here: [Display image in asp:HyperLinkField of GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/147460/Display-image-in-asp-HyperLinkField-of-GridView).